# Why won't my image display despite correct src address? [html]

Tags: html, image, src

i'm new to html and css and i've decided to utilise my time spent commuting by doing a little coding on the go. As such, i've started a practice project using Droidedit for android, on my Galaxy S7, but now i've hit a bit of a head-scratcher. Attached images below:

With full URL code and result with full URL

[image]

With relative URL code and result with relative URL

[image]

Not sure where i've gone wrong here. The image is in the same directory as the html file.

Thanks in advance peeps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that last "/" at the end after the jpg

Comment: Hmm Make sure it's a jpg it might be a png

Answer (score 0):

I guess there could be an issue with path used to show the image. Instead of following

```
<img src="internal storage/download/htmlearning/jotpage1.jpg/" ...
```

try

```
<img src="jotpage1.jpg" ...
```

since your HTML file and image file are at same folder